# wp_set_post_terms example?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin

My client has a post type that uses a lot taxonomies. I plan to put this script in a post meta box and hide the existing taxonomies.

**Do you know of a great [wp_set_post_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) example?**

I want to make this:
[image]

Look like this:
[image]

Related functions? [wp_update_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term)

Comment: I think you're looking for [wp_set_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms)

Comment: I think you might be right, question edited.

Comment: I am not sure what example you are looking for. Function itself is documented (more or less) in Codex. Do you want full metabox example with it or what?

Comment: I can make a meta box, my question really is what, if anything, do I need to wrap/include with wp_set_post_terms()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your fields like `car_specs[taxonomy_name]`, then within "save_post" just do:

```
foreach($_POST['car_specs'] as $tax => $term)
  if(taxonomy_exists($tax)) // && term_exists($term, $tax)
    wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $term, $tax);
```

Personally I wouldn't use WordPress for a auto classifieds type of website. There are PHP frameworks out there better suited for building such sites

Comment: Thanks for the starting point. This project is for an independent study program at my university.